# Using sunspot_solr search array of values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, solr, sunspot, sunspot-rails

Hi, I built a Ruby on Rails application with Sunspot Solr for searching.

```
@search = Answer.search do
  with(:question_id, @question_ids) 
  paginate :page => 1, :per_page => Answer.count
end
return question_id
```

Here i want to search this **Answer** model using array of question_ids (ex: [1,2,3,4,5]).

How to do that? Kindly help me.

Comment: Have you already read the Sunspot Solr API documentation? http://sunspot.github.io/docs/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your question and answer has association like

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :answers
end

class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :question
end
```

then you can add searchable to your questions model like this

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  searchable do
    text :title, :body
    text :answers do
      answers.map { |answer| answer.body }
    end
    integer :questions_ids, :multiple => true
  end
    // your another methods
end
```

And in your index action

```
@search = Answer.search do
  with(:questions_ids, @question_ids) 
  paginate :page => 1, :per_page => Answer.count
end
return question_id
```

I think it will help you.